# Mostrar o menor valor no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo um BD que mostra o menor valor entre três opções, cada opção representa uma coluna. Quero pegar o menor valor de uma linha onde contenha esses três valores.

Comment: Olá! Você já chegou a tentar alguma coisa? Compartilhe ai com a gente por favor =)

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o `LEAST()`:

```
SELECT LEAST(1,2,3);
```

Resultado:

```
1
```

Ele irá retornar o menor valor entre os valores *inseridos na função*.

---

No seu caso faça:

```
SELECT LEAST(ColunaA, ColunaB, ColunaC) FROM Tabela
```

Dessa forma você vai pegar o menor valor entre as três tabelas de cada linha.

Comment: E se eu precisar saber qual é a coluna com o menor valor?

Comment: @Luanpedro Você pode usar um `CASE LEAST(a, b, c) WHEN a THEN 'a' WHEN b THEN 'b' ELSE 'c'`, algo por aí. Talvez tenha alguma coisa que faça isso *automaticamente*, mas só pesquisando.