# Como pesquisar o menor valor entre as colunas?

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

Tenho uma tabela com as campos produtos, preco1, preco2, preco3.

Como faço para mostrar o produto com menor preço?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dê um exemplo dos dados contidos nas tabelas e o resultado que você espera com esses dados

Comment: [MIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) não resolveria? Veja essa pergunta relacionada também: [Mostrar o menor valor no MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194954/66203)

Comment: SELECT min(preco) FROM tabela

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT produto, LEAST(preco1, preco2, preco3) FROM precos WHERE codigo=?
```

O operador [`least()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least), irá selecionar o menor argumento de uma determinada *query*.

> Com dois ou mais argumentos, retorna o menor argumento (valor mínimo)...Se os argumentos compreendem uma mistura de números e *strings*, eles são comparados como números.

Para atualizar o `melhorpreco`, basta executar a seguinte *query*:

```
UPDATE precos SET melhorpreco = LEAST(preco1, preco2, preco3) WHERE codigo=?
```

---

#### Notas

Onde foram colocadas as `?` você deve inserir o código do registro que deseja fazer a alteração.

Pode ver este [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd8fd0/6) que demonstra o que você quer também.

Comment: Obrigada. O access não aceita esta função

Comment: Você poderia ter informado qual o seu SGBD na pergunta. Viu qual o problema de não elaborar uma pergunta completamente? Recomendo para evitar problemas posteriores: [tour]

Comment: Sim, eu esqueci. Sorry.